# How to sum all columns in an association and divide by the count to get the average in postgesql / rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
end

class Visit < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :building
end

class Building < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :visits
end
```

I have the above relationships. A visit has a `start_at` and `end_at`, which are timestamps. I am trying to find the average time a user spends at a building. I have the following query.

```rb
visits.select('(SUM(CAST(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM end_at) AS integer)) - SUM(CAST(EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM start_at) AS integer))) / COUNT(visits) AS avg_time_spent')
```

This "works" but it only gives me the difference in seconds for each visit, not the average for them all. So let's say I have four visits, 2 that are 2 hours, 1 that is 4 hours, and 1 that is 1 hour; for a total of 9hours. The `avg_time_spent` *should* be 2.25 hours. Thanks for any help able to be offered.

- I have tried some of the answers found on SO. I've tried a sub query with a `UNION ALL`, `GROUPING SETS` to no avail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Depending on from which side you're coming from you can do this in the following ways:

```rb
Visit
  .group(:user_id, :building_id)
  .pluck(:user_id, :building_id, 'AVG("visits"."end_at" - "visits"."start_at")')
  .map { |*ids, visit_duration| [ids, visit_duration] }
  .to_h
```

Produces a hash with a combination of the user and building id as key and the average visit time as value.

If you're coming from a single user:

```rb
user.visits.group(:building_id)
    .pluck(:building_id, 'AVG("visits"."end_at" - "visits"."start_at")')
    .to_h
```

Or if you're coming from a building:

```rb
building.visits.group(:user_id)
        .pluck(:user_id, 'AVG("visits"."end_at" - "visits"."start_at")')
        .to_h
```

I hope the above gives you some inspiration. This answer works only with the ids to keep the query simple. If you want the entire instance set as key you can look them up with a separate query.

---

An example of this could be:

```rb
average_time = user.visits # ...

buildings = average_time.keys.zip(Building.find(average_time.keys)).to_h
average_time.transform_keys! { |building_id| buildings[building_id] }

# The simpler approach
#
#     average_time.transform_keys!(&:Building.method(:find))
#
# results in a 1+N query
```

Comment: I hadn't had enough coffee today when I asked. lol. But I can use your single user approach, and scope the visits to a building, then pluck. That's works great! Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using postgres' average function `AVG`:

```
averaged = user.visits.select("AVG(end_at - start_at) as average_interval, building_id").group(:building_id).preload(:building)
averaged.map{|o| [o.building, o.average_interval]}
```

Comment: I get a missing attribute error for `building_id`. If I try to call `.first` to check the avg I get the error that `visits.id` is missing from the group by clause . I'm trying to get the query to return the average. I don't want to map over the results, that would take up too much memory/time. Also I don't know what the purpose of the mapping is.

Comment: @MikeHeft I forgot to add `building_id` to select list, see updated